# infinity value error after token regex command

Tags: mallet

I'm trying to use the command `--token-regex '[\p{L}\p{M}]+',` with the usual commands for importing text, so that mallet can read german text. No error-message is shown and a new file created. It is suspiciously small however.
Then, using `train-topics` to run a topic-model, the following error message is shown:

```
3       5
4       5
5       5
6       5
7       5
8       5
9       5
Infinite value after topic 0 0
<350> LL/token: ´┐¢
Infinite value after topic 0 0
<360> LL/token: ´┐¢
Infinite value after topic 0 0
<370> LL/token: ´┐¢
Infinite value after topic 0 0
<380> LL/token: ´┐¢
Infinite value after topic 0 0
<390> LL/token: ´┐¢
```

I've been trying to fix this for hours using different token regex commands but nothing seems to work, any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: I ran into the same problem on Windows when I tried Gensim's wrapper for Mallet. (it didn't appear to be related to regex commands). Switching to Linux fixed it for me.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Windows, try something like:

```
--token-regex "[\p{L}\p{M}]+"
```

UPD: you can find the discussion on "single vs double quotes in cmd.exe" here: [What does single quote do in windows batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173825/what-does-single-quote-do-in-windows-batch-files)

Comment: even though people often do just want the answer, it is preferable if you provide an explanation.

Comment: OK, thanks for the useful suggestion. However, minuses for my very first attempt to help people on stackoverflow look very discouraging.