# Open text file via batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to access a text file using batch when a user enters a certain command. I have tried doing

```
start E:\Programming\Important\Folder\Textfile
Cls
```

And it closes the cmd window but wont open the file. Does someone mind telling me what I did wrong? (sorry for the code not being in the gray box im using the web browser on phone)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is `Textfile` has no file extension, so windows does not know how to open it. Instead of using `start` you could use the `notepad` command, as `notepad.exe` is in the search path of the system, you can simply write:

```
notepad 'E:\Programming\Important\Folder\Textfile'
```

This will open your file.

Comment: better to put single quotes around filepath

Comment: @EddyJawed that won't work because [single quotes don't have any meaning in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24173825/995714). You need to use double quotes if there are special characters in the file name

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with PowerShell, like so:

say we want to open 2 files in Sublime Text:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\subl.exe" -ArgumentList D:\PathToMyFile\myFile.txt, D:\PathToMySecondFile\myFile.txt
```