# Java unable to find class when executed via PHP, identical command works in CLI

Tags: java, php

I'm attempting to run a small Java class from within a PHP script. It works as expected on Linux, but when the same script is executed on Windows I receive:

> Could not find or load main class JDBCProxy

Here's the relevant PHP:

```
$classpath = join(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'JDBCProxy',
    dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'JDBCProxy'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'libs'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'json-simple-1.1.1.jar',
));

$cmd = sprintf("java -cp '%s' JDBCProxy", $classpath);

...

$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

The output of `sprintf` is

```
java -cp 'C:\worker\lib\DB\JDBCProxy;C:\worker\lib\DB\JDBCProxy\libs\json-simple-1.1.1.jar' JDBCProxy
```

When run directly from the command line, this works as expected. **Why isn't Java able to locate the class when run from the context of PHP?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, use double quotes (`"`) instead of single ones (`'`).

See [Including all the jars in a directory within the Java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath) for Java specifics and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24181667/6204612) for Windows' treatment of single quotes.

Comment: Wow. Thank you, friend. It was made all the more confusing that it worked in the command prompt with single quotes, but double quotes within the context of PHP does it.