# Why do arguments in single-quotes not work as expected for gcloud on Windows?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

While using gcloud flags like `filter` and `format` on Windows, passing in single-quoted arguments doesn't yield the expected result.

For example, running `gcloud compute instances list --filter='status=TERMINATED'` returns an empty list, even though there are terminated instances present.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that single-quoted arguments don't produce the expected result is because cmd.exe [doesn't use single quotes for this purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173825/what-does-single-quote-do-in-windows-batch-files).

Fix: Use double quotes.

Example: `gcloud compute instances list --filter="status=TERMINATED"`