# 'hskip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: python, shell, cmd

```
cmd = "perl -pe 's|hskip(.*?)(cm\\|in\\|pt\\|mm\\|em)|hspace{\\1\\2}|g' %s > %s"%(input_file, 
output_file)
ret = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
if ret != 0:
   logging.error('FAILED: %s'%cmd)
```

### Error output:

```
'hskip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
2021-02-21 16:39:46,454 root  ERROR    FAILED: perl -pe 's|hskip(.*?)(cm\|in\|pt\|mm\|em)|hspace{\1\2}|g' .\data\sample\im2latex_formulas.lst > .\data\sample\formul`as.norm.lst     
2021-02-21 16:39:46,457 root  INFO  Jobs finished**
```

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Not a [latex] question! :)

Comment: Not a [perl] question either

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows, you should use double quotes instead of single quotes:

For example:

```
cmd = 'perl -pe "s|hskip|hspace|g" in.txt > out.txt'
ret = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

See also:

- [How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line.](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)
- [Differences between single and double quotes in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51080215/2173773)