# Publishing a RAML file to Exchange via Exchange REST Api error

Tags: curl, automation, mulesoft, raml, anypoint-platform

I have been following MuleSoft's tutorial regarding publishing an asset to exchange:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/exchange-api,

[this is the command used: (under publish an asset module)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofrti.png)

When I [execute this command using cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvj66.png), I receive the following error but I'm not able to pinpoint what's the error.

**The command:**

```
curl -v -H 'Authorization: bearer b90ed1ce-671c-4726-9d25-4aacd7cb8bb4'
-H 'x-sync-publication: true'
-F 'name=RAML asset name' 
-F 'description=Description of the asset' 
-F 'keywords=this, is, the, best, raml'
-F 'dependencies=68ef9520-24e9-4cf2-b2f5-620025690913:training-american-flight-data-type:1.0.1,68ef9520-24e9-4cf2-b2f5-620025690913:training-american-flights-example:1.0.1'
-F 'properties.mainFile=american-flights-api.raml'
-F 'properties.apiVersion=v1' 
-F 'files.raml.zip=training-american-flights-api-1.0.0-raml.zip' https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/api/v2/organizations/:org id/assets/:org id/doc-api-v2/1.0.0
```

[The error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XadyV.png)

```
* Could not resolve host: bearer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: bearer
* Could not resolve host: b90ed1ce-671c-4726-9d25-4aacd7cb8bb4'
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: b90ed1ce-671c-4726-9d25-4aacd7cb8bb4'
* Could not resolve host: true'
* Closing connection 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: true'
* Could not resolve host: asset
* Closing connection 3
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: asset
* Could not resolve host: name'
* Closing connection 4
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: name'
* Could not resolve host: of
* Closing connection 5
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: of
* Could not resolve host: the
* Closing connection 6
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: the
* Could not resolve host: asset'
* Closing connection 7
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: asset'
* Could not resolve host: is,
* Closing connection 8
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: is,
* Could not resolve host: the,
* Closing connection 9
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: the,
* Could not resolve host: best,
* Closing connection 10
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: best,
* Could not resolve host: raml'
* Closing connection 11
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: raml'
*   Trying 52.87.53.99:443...
* Connected to anypoint.mulesoft.com (52.87.53.99) port 443 (#12)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* schannel: ALPN, offering http/1.1
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> POST /exchange/api/v2/organizations/d44a45b6-2599-4559-9a4e-f4fef4c5500b/assets/d44a45b6-2599-4559-9a4e-f4fef4c5500b/doc-api-v2/1.0.0 HTTP/1.1
> Host: anypoint.mulesoft.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1031
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------daa7e3a71c8392fb
>
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
< content-security-policy: default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< cross-origin-embedder-policy: require-corp
< cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
< cross-origin-resource-policy: same-origin
< Date: Wed, 22 Jun 2022 06:11:50 GMT
< etag: W/"e0-0kCi5++SWwjWlVDLUPqO3gvy8eU"
< expect-ct: max-age=0
< expires: 0
< origin-agent-cluster: ?1
< pragma: no-cache
< referrer-policy: no-referrer
< Server: nginx
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< surrogate-control: no-store
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-dns-prefetch-control: off
< x-download-options: noopen
< x-envoy-decorator-operation: xapi-service.exchange.svc.cluster.local:80/*
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 12
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
< x-request-id: 941df740-8566-43d5-b647-07599048492f
< x-xss-protection: 0
< Content-Length: 224
< Connection: keep-alive
<
{"name":"BadRequestError","status":400,"message":"Request failed to validate against RAML definition","details":[{"type":"header","dataPath":"authorization","keyword":"required","message":"invalid header (required, true)"}]}* Connection #12 to host anypoint.mulesoft.com left intact
```

As a RAML file I used the same one in the documentation as a sample. It is available in this documentation under RAML section:

https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/exchange-experience-api/minor/2.0/pages/Asset%20Creation/

The organization id and the group id are the same, the asset id hold the name of the uploaded doc and the version is 1.0.0 and I added an access token so the API resulted in:
`https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/api/v2/organizations/:org id/assets/:group id/doc-api-v2/1.0.0`

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. Adding the text of the command and error as you did is the only need, unless the error is graphical in nature, which is not this case.

Comment: Maybe the example used is too old. Try with the latest version of the American Flights API: https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/68ef9520-24e9-4cf2-b2f5-620025690913/training-american-flights-api/

Comment: @aled I downloaded the zip file from the last version and tried the same command yet it is giving me the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080215/differences-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-cmd#:~:text=The%20short%20answer%20is%20that,and%20iterate%20over%20the%20output.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates the the request is missing the `Authorization` header and the screenshot of the execution confirms it. It seems that the execution doesn't match the curl command shared.

Note that it would have been easier to find if you share the complete command and execution output as one block of text.

Comment: done, however I added an access token and the raml file contain no basic auth such as client id and client secret. Do you advice to add a client id and secret to the curl command?

Comment: Try replacing the single quotes by double quotes.

Comment: The problem is most probably the use of single quotes if you are using windows cmd as cmd treats single quotes like any other character. You will need to use double quotes like aled mentioned