pushbullet InvalidKeyError on Raspberry Pi
I am trying to send pictures to my phone from a Raspberry Pi using the Pushbullet package. However, I am encountering an InvalidKeyError when running the package on the Raspberry Pi. Strangely, the same code works perfectly on my computer. I am using the latest version of Python (3.13.1) and have verified my API key multiple times to ensure it was entered correctly. Does anyone have any suggestions for resolving this issue?
Here is my code:
from pushbullet import Pushbullet

api_key = 'o.*************************'
pb = Pushbullet(api_key)

When I run this on my pi, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python/push_bullet.py", line 6, in <module>
    pb = Pushbullet(api_key)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pushbullet/pushbullet.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.refresh()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pushbullet/pushbullet.py", line 354, in refresh
    self._load_devices()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pushbullet/pushbullet.py", line 71, in _load_devices
    resp_dict = self._get_data(self.DEVICES_URL)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pushbullet/pushbullet.py", line 61, in _get_data
    raise InvalidKeyError()
pushbullet.errors.InvalidKeyError



------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue

And here is the curl request I am using:
curl --header 'Access-Token: <your_access_token_here>' \ api.pushbullet.com/v2/users/me


Is the raspberry pi on a different network than your regular computer?

No, same network.

Hmm.  You could make a small python script to fetch that url, and see what response you get.  The response body content might contain something useful.

Would that be using the curl command? I'm not exactly sure how.

I meant using python, but I imagine curl would give the same result.  So yes, try that first.

using the following curl command:
{
curl --header 'Access-Token: <your_access_token_here>' 
https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/users/me
}
I got "the system cannot find the file specified"

That sounds like you mistyped one of the arguments and your system thought it was supposed to be a filename.  Can you edit the question and put the exact curl command there?

Also, why are you sending the api key in an Access-Token header?  I'm not sure that is the right way to do it.  Did you see a pushbullet example that did that?

Yes, it is from the API Quick Start in the Pushbullet documentation: https://docs.pushbullet.com/

Ah, I see.  Did that curl command succeed when you ran it?

No, it returned "the system cannot find the file specified".

I wonder if that is because of the backslash.  The curl command in the pushbullet documentation had a backslash just to indicate that it was too long to fit on one line in their example.  Try taking that out and run it again.

Same result. I uploaded a screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/OjqVEFB

Well, that's odd.  Maybe the curl command itself is somehow damaged or missing on your computer?  If you just run curl with no arguments, what happens?  Do you still get the same error?

It seems to be working. It replies with curl: try 'curl --help' for more information

In that screenshot I see that the access token is enclosed in angle brackets <o............> Are those brackets really supposed to be there?

I think the single-quotes are the problem.  The windows cmd shell does not recognize single-quotes.  You have to use double-quotes.  See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/51080215/494134

And because the single-quotes were not recognized, it was treating the < character inside the quotes as a command input redirection.

Finally got something. It says there is an invalid request https://imgur.com/a/KNxRaKR

I think you need to put https:// before api.pushbullet.com.  Without that, curl defaults to HTTP instead of HTTPS.
