# How to escape ' for linux command in windows terminal?

Tags: git, cmd, window

I am trying to run the following git command using windows terminal:

`git submodule foreach  --recursive 'git add --all'`

Apparently there is a problem with  `'`. How can I escape that?

```
git add --all: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
git add --all: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: `'` has no special meaning for Windows command processor `cmd.exe` in comparison to Linux shell interpreters. Use `git submodule foreach --recursive "git add --all"` which could be used also in Linux shell script in this case. In a Linux terminal run `man sh` and read about the difference on quoting with `'` and quoting with `"`.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173825/what-does-single-quote-do-in-windows-batch-files ?