# calling activities:list fails on using parameter `mine=true` (Youtube Data API V3)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been trying to use the API to retrieve my activities but I'm receiving the following JSON error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The request is not properly authorized.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The request is not properly authorized.",
                "domain": "youtube.activity",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

, although I use `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?mine=true&key={my_api_key}&part=contentDetails` and I use OAuth2 client to get an access token which I use on calling the API.

I tried to use the samples but I'm receiving the same error.
[image: error ocurring on using the sample]

Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

---

**More details**
I use the given link in postman with the `GET` method and I put a valid access token in the token field with `TYPE=OAuth2` and `Prefix=Bearer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official specification of the [`Activities.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) API endpoint, for to be able to use its `mine` request parameter, you have to issue the call to the endpoint while passing to it proper credentials:

> [**`mine`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list#mine) (boolean)
> This parameter can only be used in a properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). Set this parameter's value to true to retrieve a feed of the authenticated user's activities.

Therefore, using an API key is not sufficient (neither is required when issuing a properly authorized request).

Do note that the JSON error response obtained from the API agrees entirely with the specification quoted above.

---

According to the [official (programming language agnostic) procedure](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#offline), for to obtain a valid fresh access token from the API, issue a simple `curl` instance as follows:

```bash
$ curl \
--data 'grant_type=refresh_token' \
--data-urlencode "client_id=$CLIENT_ID" \
--data-urlencode "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" \
--data-urlencode "refresh_token=$REFRESH_TOKEN" \
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
```

Above, `$CLIENT_ID` and `$CLIENT_SECRET` are the values of the corresponding properties of your client secrets JSON file you've got from Google's developers console. The `$REFRESH_TOKEN` is your (long-lived) refresh token you've obtained upon running a successful OAuth2 authentication/authorization flow.

The output obtained from `curl` when successful would look like:

```json
{
  "access_token": "...",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "scope": "...",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

---

A call to the `Activities.list` endpoint as yours above using `curl` is immediate:

```bash
$ curl \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?mine=true&part=contentDetails&maxResults=25'
```

The parameter `$ACCESS_TOKEN` above is your freshly obtained valid access token; the output of `curl` would look like:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#activityListResponse",
  "etag": "...",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#activity",
      "etag": "...",
      "id": "...",
      "contentDetails": {
        ...
      }
    },
    ...
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": ...,
    "resultsPerPage": 25
  }
}
```

For to run the above `curl` commands on a Windows machine under `CMD.exe` -- assuming that you've substitued the `$`-variables yourself manually --, do replace the [backslash character at the end of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21000752/8327971) above with the caret character, `^`. The percent character `%` should be doubled, i.e. should be replaced with `%%`, and the [single quote characters `'` should be replaced with double-quote characters `"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24181667/8327971).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226522/discussion-on-answer-by-stvar-calling-activitieslist-fails-on-using-parameter).

Comment: @stvar plz, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65519158/youtube-data-api-quota-on-using-the-same-google-client-on-different-devices