# Youtube data API quota on using the same google client on different devices

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The current youtube API quota is 10,000 units/day.

So what if I created an app and this app has 100 copies installed on different 100 devices and all of them use different IPs, would the quota be 10,000 units/day for every device (1M/day) or the 10,000 units would be distributed among the different copies?

Note that the requests will be executed on different devices. this is an embedded app., not a cloud one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[10,000 units/day](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) is project based, not user based.  IP address won't affect anything.

[image]

As you can see from the above image on the Queries per minute per user is user based, and detected via ip address, sending the quotauser parameter along with the request or sending an authorization header containing an access token.

In order to get around your 10k quota in this manner you would need to create 100 projects on google developer console and create credietnals for each of those projects and then each project would have 10k quota.  However the drawback would be trying to get 100 projects though the google verification process.

You could just request an extension of your quota if you need more quota.

**Additional Clarifications**

- API key Used to access public data only and identifies your application to google
- Client id and client secrete used to create a access token, will identify both the application and the user to google once a user is authorized and you are sending an access token authorization header with your request.
- The quotaUser and userIp parameters can only be used for anonymous requests with some Google apis this has changed recently i am not sure if it still works with YouTube api private calls.   userIp allows you to send any ip address with the request, and QuotaUser allows you to send any string for example your internal user id for the user making the requests. In the past this allowed for some hacking / work around for the per user quotas.

None of the above information will really help you as the quota you are trying to get around is a project based quota and not a user based quota.  Its detecting the project associated with your client id / api key (depending upon what you are using) changing the IP or generating a new client under your project isnt going to help.

Really just request more quota

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways an app is identified by the API:

1. the API key that the app uses when invoking the API endpoints (for reading only public data), or
2. the credentials data (i.e. access token) the app makes use of when calling in various endpoints (for reading only public data pertaining to any YouTube channel, or, otherwise, for reading/updating/deleting public and/or private data pertaining the  YouTube account/channel that granted permissions of operation to the respective app).

Therefore, from the point of view of the API, it doesn't really matter if you are running `N` different instances of your app (i.e. programs running on concrete computers). The API accounts for the quota consumption of a given project created through Google developers console.

In this context of an app (as a concrete program) running on several machines that share API keys and/or credentials data, I recommend warmly to get familiar with the content of the [DTOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies) specifications.

Comment: I target the second scope. If there is a direct answer for "Does google count for the requests for the client id or for the devices (IPs) execute the requests?", please let me know. or if there is a specific paragraph in the given link related to the question, plz let me know.

Comment: The quota is accounted per project (that is per Google project).