# Docker run env variable does not work with single quotes?

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I was running the following command:

```
docker run -e 'SOME_ENV_VARIABLE=somevalue' somecommand
```

And this did not pass the env variable to `somecommand` (Note: `SOME_ENV_VARIABLE` and `somevalue` did not have un-escaped single quotes, they were capital snake case and lowercase respectively without special character.

Later, I tried:

```
docker run -e "SOME_ENV_VARIABLE=somevalue" somecommand
```

And this somehow worked (note the double quotes).

Why is this? I have seen documentation with single quotes.

I tried this on `Windows`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotation is handled by your shell - since you are on windows, that is `cmd.exe`. And, from what I understand, since [`cmd.exe` does not handle single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173825/what-does-single-quoting-do-in-windows-batch-files), it will pass that argument with the quotes to `docker`.

It would work on Linux though (which usually has the `bash` shell), being the the environment many people would use `docker` on, and as such the reason it is present in a lot of documentation.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense, but I'm wondering why it didn't work inside an alpine image either?

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question adding what exactly you tried to run and what error message you got - Alpine's shell definitely does handle single quotes, which can be tested by running `ls '/'`. It would be transparent to the application, which would not receive the quotes at all.

Comment: Turns out it didn't work on Alpine, because of some other problem and spit out the exact same error, and worked on Alpine, by the time I had resolved that. Edited the question to Windows only for future readers

Comment: @Vedant How did you fix it on alpine? Facing the same issue.